# "Flexible"(?) Rails Database

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I'm not sure if the title is clear. I'm not too sure what the kind of answer I'm looking for is called. I've been searching and searching and can't seem to find the answer.

Here's what I want to do:

I want a user to create a workout consisting of x sets, x reps, and x type.

I know I can do for example;

```
create_table "workouts", :force => true do |t|
  t.string    "workout name"
  t.integer   "sets"
  t.integer   "reps"
  t.string    "type"
end
```

But in this method, it only allows *one type* of set to be written/workout.

I want the ability to add *multiple* types of sets/workout.

So for example;

```
workout name: monday morning
sets: 2 reps: 4 type: "bicep curl"
sets: 4 reps 23 type: "bench press"
etc..
```

If my explanation is too unclear or if maybe I'm just confused please feel free to point out. All help is appreciated. Thanks for viewing!

Comment: Based on my understanding you want polymorphic association http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations?

Comment: @vinodadhikary, no need for polymorphic associations here. A simple `has_many` and `belongs_to` is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a table `workouts` and `workout_details` and link them together:

```
create_table "workouts", :force => true do |t|
  t.string :name
end

create_table "workout_details", :force => true do |t|
  t.references :workout
  t.integer    :sets
  t.integer    :reps
  t.string     :type
end
```

And your models would look something like this:

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workout_details
end

class WorkoutDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :workout
end
```

If you set it up like this, you create several workout details:

```
bicep_curl = WorkoutDetail.new
bicep_curl.type = 'bicep curl'
bicep_curl.sets = 2
bicep_curl.reps = 4
bicep_curl.save

bench_press = WorkoutDetail.new
bench_press.type = 'bench press'
bench_press.sets = 4
bench_press.reps = 23
bench_press.save
```

and add them to a workout:

```
workout = Workout.new
workout.name = 'monday morning'
workout.workout_details << bicep_curl
workout.workout_details << bench_press
workout.save
```

To retrieve your workout, you can do this:

```
workout = Workout.where(:name => 'monday morning').first
puts "workout name: #{workout.name}"

workout.workout_details.each do |wd|
  puts "sets: #{wd.sets} reps: #{wd.reps} type: #{wd.type}"
end
```

Output:

```
workout name: monday morning
sets: 2 reps: 4 type: bicep curl
sets: 4 reps: 23 type: bench press
```